# Left key to move back to end of the previous line

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example, assume you are at the start of a new line. Pressing LEFT on the keypad does not move the cursor to the end of the previous line.

Similarly assume you are at the end of a line, pressing RIGHT on the keypad doesn't move the cursor to a new line.

How do I enable this behavior? Note this is the default behavior in Sublime Text 3.

Here LEFT and RIGHT are simply <- and ->, on the keyboard and not the numeric ones.

Comment: Do you mean the numpad when you say the "keypad" - as in the left arrow on the number 4?

Comment: Sorry I mean the normal  <- and -> keys

Comment: In that case, they work for me.  Are you sure you don't have an extension or keybinding that conflicts with left/right arrows?  In Keyboard Shortcuts, click the little keyboard icon to the right of the input box and type a leftArrow.  Do you get a binding to `cursorLeft`?

Comment: Yes you are right, something is wrong with my VS Code.